# MS Access 2016 Import multiple CSV files

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to import multiple csv files, all in the same directory into MS Access 2016.

This is the VBA module I currently have, thanks to [physics2010](https://superuser.com/questions/699967/import-a-large-number-of-csv-files-into-access),but it's not working. Any tips?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function DoImport()

Dim strPathFile As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = True

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the CSV files
strPath = "C:\Users\xxx"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "Table1"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames


' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()

Loop


   MsgBox "done"


End Function
```

Comment: You wrote "it's not working": do you get an error message? Did you try debugging the code to see where it fails?

Comment: It just does nothing at this stage. I must admit, I am new at Access, but I do have some coding experience. It seems as though it never gets into the While loop, as if strFile's length is never greater than 1. That's odd, because I do have multiple csv files in the directory.

Comment: Try changing `strPath = "C:\Users\xxx"` to `strPath = "C:\Users\xxx\"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Atzmon](https://superuser.com/users/589157/atzmon), the problem was in my strPath, instead of `strPath = "C:\Users\xxx"` it should be `strPath = "C:\Users\xxx\"`

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you to import into one data file? The code works, but it imports each file as a separate database every time I do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).