# How to include text import specs into a batch import script for MS Access 2013+?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, import

This code to import multiple CSV files into MS Access works really well for me: [Import a large number of .csv files into Access](https://superuser.com/questions/699967/import-a-large-number-of-csv-files-into-access)

The one thing I would like to add is an import spec that imports each field as SHORT TEXT. I have the spec saved as "GPS1" but not a clue how to add it into the batch import code.

I have tried this

```
docmd.RunSavedImportExport ("GPS1")
```

but no luck.

Comment: I figured it out! All I had to do is add the spec name inside this line

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "gps1", strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

Answer (score 0):

The sample code has a line...

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
```

Simply add your import specification to that line...

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim,"GPS1" , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
```